# Does 窈窕淑女，君子好逑 mean “There's a good maiden fair / Whom a young man is wooing”？

Tags: word

About these two sentences from the Book of Poems, my understanding is that a good girl is always the desired target of a man of virtue, something like the beginning words of Pride and Prejudice--It is a truth universally acknowledged, that a single man in possession of a good fortune, must be in want of a wife.

"There's a good maiden fair/Whom a young man is wooing" is the interpretation of the same by a Chinese translator named 许渊冲, which is not the right translation of the original. He must have mistaken the word 逑 for 求.

Comment: The translation wasn't very good but consider "wooing" means "A man's courting of a woman; seeking the affections of a woman (usually with the hope of marriage), it is not too far off from its original meaning either - a fair lady is the desirable match (好逑) of the gentleman. Note "求" has the meaning of "to seek" or "to look for", which is fine in the reverse translation (Chinese - English).

Answer (score 1):

In my copy of 诗经 each line is rendered in more modern Chinese as well:

窈窕淑女: 美丽的善良的姑娘 A beautiful, kindhearted maiden,

君子好逑：是君子追求的心仪对象 this gentlemen would fain pursue